# Get Amazon Items Rank using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver

I want to get the **rank** of all Amazon items on the page using the following Chrome Extension:
[DS Amazon Quick View](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ds-amazon-quick-view/jkompbllimaoekaogchhkmkdogpkhojg)

To do so, I use selenium to log into my chrome profile (where the extension is already installed) and try to scrape the rank html info. However, "find_all" return an empty object:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup    

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument(r"--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\Edo\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data") # get your owm chrome local directory
options.add_argument(r'--profile-directory=Default') 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe", options=options) #get your own exe directory
driver.get("https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Kindle-Store/zgbs/digital-text/ref=zg_bs_unv_digital-text_1_154606011_1")
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source.encode('utf-8').strip(), 'html.parser')
print(soup.find_all("div", {"class":"xtaqv-result"})))

>>> 0
```

Comment: The link you shared is an image. Are you trying to scrap information from an image?

Comment: This is the link to download the chrome extension is the following: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ds-amazon-quick-view/jkompbllimaoekaogchhkmkdogpkhojg

Comment: Whereas the page I am trying to scrape is on amazon and it is the following: https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Kindle-Store/zgbs/digital-text/ref=zg_bs_unv_digital-text_1_154606011_1

Comment: The extension add some info (that I want to scrape) to the items in the Amazon link

Comment: Any specific reason, you want to get the information from extension.  Is it not accessible from amazon?

Comment: yes but it is much more time consuming as I have to scrape the link for each item and then iterate links in order to upload each single item page and scrape the rank

Comment: so I have to upload 50 pages and scrape them instead of 1 single scrape...

Comment: Your browser is not opening with extension.  You need to load extension when launch browser.  To understand it better, just keep in mind, selenium launches browser like you open your browser in incognito mode.  No cached login details, no extension etc until u specifically add it in chrome profile before launching. Thats the reason you are not getting anything

Comment: This is not true. The code I provide open Chrome and log wiht my profile (see above the two option.add_argument() do exactly this). In fact, I see all the info provided by the extension.

Comment: And this is the reason why I wrote this post

Comment: Agree, I missed that part. Between, I have shared the answer, hope it will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 4 things in this page:

1. Items get loads when you scroll down (Initially it shows only 30 items)
2. Items rankings also loads with scroll
3. There is pagination if we want to get items from other pages
4. Correct locator (Xpath, CSS etc)

Therefore in our code, if we are not waiting for page/rankings to load completely, we will not get values.

Below code retunes all names and ranking details for all the available pages(in this case only 2):

**Imports:**

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By



options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument(r"--user-data- 
dir=C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data")
options.add_argument(r'--profile-directory=Default')
PATH = r"path to your\chromedriver.exe"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"your chromedriver exe path\chromedriver.exe", options=options)
driver.get(
        "https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Kindle-Store/zgbs/digital-text/ref=zg_bs_unv_digital-text_1_154606011_1")
    sleep(10)
    
    
    def pagescroll():
        for x in range(9):
            driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'body').send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
            sleep(2)
    
    
    def get_items():
        pagescroll()
        sleep(5)
        allnames = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='gridItemRoot']//a//span//div")
        allRanks = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@class='xtaqv-result']")
        for index in range(len(allnames)):
            print(f"--------------------------Item : {index + 1}----------------------------------------")
            print(allnames[index].text)
            print("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
            print(allRanks[index].text)
    
    
    get_items()
    nextElement = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.a-text-center > ul > li.a-last > a")
    counter = 1
    try:
        while nextElement.is_displayed():
            counter = counter + 1
            print("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
            print(f"{counter} : <- page scrapping started")
            print("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
            nextElement.click()
            sleep(5)
            get_items()
    except:
        print("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
        print("There is no more page left with items")
        print("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
    
    driver.quit()


**Output:** Not all items shared as charcaters are going beyond specified limit.
--------------------------Item : 1----------------------------------------
Taste
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#1 in Kindle Store (Top 100)
#1 in Contemporary Romance (Kindle Store)
#1 in Romantic Comedy (Kindle Store)
#1 in Romantic Comedy (Books)
--------------------------Item : 2----------------------------------------
Family Money
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#2 in Kindle Store (Top 100)
#1 in Domestic Thrillers (Kindle Store)
#1 in Psychological Thrillers (Books)
#1 in Literature & Fiction (Kindle Store)
--------------------------Item : 3----------------------------------------
Run, Rose, Run: A Novel
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#3 in Kindle Store (Top 100)
#1 in Southern United States Fiction
#2 in Literature & Fiction (Kindle Store)
#2 in Crime Thrillers (Kindle Store)
--------------------------Item : 4----------------------------------------
Reminders of Him: A Novel
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#4 in Kindle Store (Top 100)
#1 in New Adult & College Romance (Books)
#1 in Mothers & Children Fiction
#1 in Romance (Kindle Store)
--------------------------Item : 5----------------------------------------
The Last Eligible Billionaire
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#5 in Kindle Store (Top 100)
#1 in Billionaire Romance
#2 in Romantic Comedy (Kindle Store)
#2 in Women's Romance Fiction
--------------------------Item : 6----------------------------------------
The Washington Post Digital Access
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#6 in Kindle Store (Top 100)
#1 in eNewspapers
#1 in U.S. Newspapers
--------------------------Item : 7----------------------------------------
Things We Never Got Over
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#7 in Kindle Store (Top 100)
#1 in General Humorous Fiction
#1 in Men, Women & Relationships Humor
#1 in Small Town & Rural Fiction (Kindle Store)
-
-
-
--------------------------Item : 49----------------------------------------
Heir to Love
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#49 in Kindle Store (Top 100)
#8 in New Adult & College Romance (Books)
#23 in Romance (Kindle Store)
--------------------------Item : 50----------------------------------------
America's Last Fortress: Puerto Rico's Sovereignty, China's Caribbean Belt and Road, and America's National Security
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#50 in Kindle Store (Top 100)
#1 in History of the Caribbean & West Indies
#1 in History of Latin America
#1 in International Relations (Kindle Store)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2 : <- page scrapping started
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------Item : 1----------------------------------------
Stepbrother Weekend: Filthy Dirty Desires
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#51 in Kindle Store (Top 100)
#1 in Erotic Literature & Fiction
#1 in Erotica (Kindle Store)
--------------------------Item : 2----------------------------------------
Forget-Me-Not Bombshell
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#52 in Kindle Store (Top 100)
#1 in Women's Action & Adventure Fiction
#1 in Organized Crime (Kindle Store)
#2 in Action & Adventure Romance (Kindle Store)
--------------------------Item : 3----------------------------------------
By a Thread: A Grumpy Boss Romantic Comedy
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#53 in Kindle Store (Top 100)
#2 in General Humorous Fiction
#3 in Romance Literary Fiction
#7 in Romantic Comedy (Kindle Store)
--------------------------Item : 4----------------------------------------
How To Start A Conversation And Make Friends: Revised And Updated
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#54 in Kindle Store (Top 100)
#1 in Motivational Self-Help (Kindle Store)
#1 in Running Meetings & Presentations (Kindle Store)
#1 in Healthy Relationships (Kindle Store)
--------------------------Item : 5----------------------------------------
What Lies Beyond the Veil (Of Flesh & Bone Series Book 1)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#55 in Kindle Store (Top 100)
#1 in Romantic Fantasy (Books)
#1 in Sword & Sorcery Fantasy (Books)
#1 in Greco-Roman Myth & Legend Fantasy eBooks
--------------------------Item : 6----------------------------------------
Verity
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#56 in Kindle Store (Top 100)
#7 in Psychological Thrillers (Kindle Store)
#9 in Psychological Thrillers (Books)
#14 in Romance (Kindle Store)
--------------------------Item : 7----------------------------------------
Mr. Bloomsbury: A feel-good British Billionaire Romance
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#57 in Kindle Store (Top 100)
#1 in Romance Anthologies (Books)
#1 in Romance Collections & Anthologies
#1 in Romance Anthologies (Kindle Store)
--------------------------Item : 8----------------------------------------
Put Me in Detention
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#58 in Kindle Store (Top 100)
#9 in Romantic Comedy (Kindle Store)
#10 in Romantic Comedy (Books)
#15 in Romance (Kindle Store)
--------------------------Item : 9----------------------------------------
A Place Called Freedom
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#59 in Kindle Store (Top 100)
#1 in Espionage Thrillers (Kindle Store)
#1 in Mystery Action Fiction (Kindle Store)
#1 in Historical Scottish Fiction
--------------------------Item : 10----------------------------------------
The Second Home: A Novel
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#60 in Kindle Store (Top 100)
#2 in Sibling Fiction
#4 in Sisters Fiction
#4 in Coming of Age Fiction (Books)
--------------------------Item : 11----------------------------------------
The Last Green Valley: A Novel
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#61 in Kindle Store (Top 100)
#1 in Historical Biographical Fiction
#1 in Biographical Fiction (Books)
#1 in Biographical Literary Fiction
--------------------------Item : 12----------------------------------------
Hidden: An Exciting Novel of Suspense (A Lost and Found Novel Book 1)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#62 in Kindle Store (Top 100)
#1 in Contemporary
#1 in Thrillers (Kindle Store)
#1 in Heist Thrillers
--------------------------Item : 49----------------------------------------
Sweet (Landry Family Series Book 6)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#99 in Kindle Store (Top 100)
#4 in Inspirational Romance
#5 in New Adult & College Romance (Kindle Store)
#6 in Women's New Adult & College Fiction
--------------------------Item : 50----------------------------------------
Sold on a Monday: A Novel
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#100 in Kindle Store (Top 100)
#3 in Historical Fiction (Kindle Store)
#3 in Literary Fiction (Kindle Store)
#3 in U.S. Historical Fiction
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
There is no more page left with items
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```